# MINValue in an Array and NEGATIVE_INFINITY

Tags: java, arrays

i'm learning Java and playing around with a Java programming book. I'm up to the point where they teaching me about Arrays.

So, i created an Array that takes a non specific amount of Command Line Arguments, and combined it with the books code for printing out the max value in that array. It works perfectly... Great...

But my question is, what exactly is NEGATIVE_INFINITY? And is there something similar for printing the smallest value of the array?

Cheers

```
public class MaxAndMin
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {

int length = args.length;
int[] array = new int[length];


for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  array[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
  double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
  }  
   System.out.println(max);

 }  
}
```

Comment: It is just a constant value, if you are using eclipse alike ide you can hold down ctrl+left click the negative_infinity you will see where it gets called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the IEEE 754 format, floating point numbers have three parts to them. The sign bit, the exponent, and a mantissa. The first bit is the sign bit which distinguishes positive and negative infinity in this case. The two infinities have all the exponent bits turned on and the mantissa bits zero. The way you can calculate the number is the mantissa multiplied by 2^ exponent. SO essentially they're the highest values possible, with the leading bit distinguishing between positive and negative.

I would do something similar for finding the min

```
double minVal = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i] < minVal) {
             minVal= array[i];
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find the minimum value

```
minValue = array[0];
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i] < minValue) {
             minValue = array[i];
         }
     }
```

EDIT: Here is the entire code:

```
public class MaxAndMin {

     public static void main(String[] args){

         int length = args.length;
         int[] array = new int[length];


         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             array[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
         }
         double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
         }
         System.out.println(max);


         double minValue = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             if (array[i] < minValue) minValue = array[i];
         }

         System.out.println(minValue);




     }
 };
```

Comment: With that, i get a load of errors saying that minValue isn't a symbol/cannot find symbol minValue?

Comment: Okay, I passed you only a piece of code which you need to adjust to your code, I will adjust the piece of code and post the entire code for you in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

EGATIVE_INFINITY = -1.0D / 0.0;

From the documentation:

> A constant holding the negative infinity of type double. It is equal to the value returned by Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000000L).

The computer itself can not represent infinite numbers, because it has finite memory. For example the double type represents its data in 8 bits of memory which is finite, which means that it can store finite number of numbers :). Think of this constant value as holding the smallest possible Double number which can be represented in computer.